# Kendo Editor + show("slide") is not editable in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, firefox, kendo-ui

Please refer to [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dschilling/xzftW/11/) for a working demonstration of this problem.

In Firefox (latest version, 24), if I use jQuery UI's `.show("slide", { direction: "right" })` to display a kendoEditor, the editor does not contain the value I set it with, and it is not editable.  If I use the plain old `.show()` from jQuery, then everything works fine.   It also works fine in Chrome 30 and IE 10.  Why does `.show("slide")` break the editor in Firefox, and are there any workarounds for this problem?

Html for this example:

```
<button id="btn1" type="button">Button 1</button>
<button id="btn2" type="button">Button 2</button>
<div id="div">
    <textarea data-role="editor" data-bind="value: TheValue"></textarea>
    <button id="hide" type="button">Hide</button>
</div>
```

This is the JS code that does not work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var model;
    function bindDiv(value) {
        model = kendo.observable({ TheValue: value });
        kendo.bind($('#div'), model);
        $('#div').show("slide", { direction: "right" });
        //$('#div').show();
    }
    $('#div').hide();
    $('#btn1').click(function () { bindDiv('hello'); });
    $('#btn2').click(function () { bindDiv('goodbye'); });
    $('#hide').click(function () {
        console.log(model.get('TheValue'));
        $('#div').hide("slide", { direction: "right" });
        //$('#div').hide();
    });
});
```

Clicking `btn1` should result in the editor being display with the text `"hello"`, and then clicking "Hide" should display the edited text in the console.
If you replace those two `"slide"` lines with the plain commented-out versions, then it works fine (but doesn't look as cool).

Does anyone know why this doesn't work, or what I can do about it?

**Update:**

Before the animation plays, everything is OK - the body of the editor's iframe has the correct content and is marked with the `contenteditable` attribute.  After the animation completes, the body of the iframe is wiped clean - no content, no attributes.  I'm still trying to figure out why and what to do about it.

Comment: seems to be working fine. what is the issue?

Comment: It is working fine in Chrome30 but it is indeed not working in FF24...

Comment: Thanks @nemesv, you're right.  Out of Firefox, Chrome, and IE, it's only Firefox where this is not working.  Updated post to reflect this.

Comment: Updated JSFiddle to spit out edited output to verify whether editor is indeed working correctly or not.

Comment: Ohhh.  :(  Where did that answer go?  It might not have been quite right, but it was still helpful.  I was going to give you an upvote.

Comment: (sorry i just see your answer :(, i put another update ... :/  )

Comment: This is probably related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14864821/jquery-ui-effect-causes-iframe-reload

Comment: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=254144.  :(  It's a Firefox bug that has been open for 9 years.  And it leads to "cantfix" bugs in jQuery UI.  Example: http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/5166

Comment: @DanielSchilling yeah, I've also found those bug reports yesterday, so I'm also convinced that you're experiencing this bug. Have you tried out upgrade your Kendo UI to the latest version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you upgrade your KenoUI version to the latest **Q2 2013 (version 2013.2.716)** then the Kendo Editor has a [new method called: `refresh`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/editor#methods-refresh) which

> `refresh`
>   Reinitializes the editing area iframe. Should be used after
>   moving the editor in the DOM.

So it does exactly what you need,  because the animation moves the editor iframe you need to call refresh when it finishes:

```
$('#div').show("slide", { direction: "right" }, function () {
    var editor = $("#editor").data("kendoEditor");
    editor.refresh();
});
```

To make this work you also need to change your view and give an id to you textarea:

```
<div id="div">
    <textarea id="editor" data-role="editor" data-bind="value: TheValue">
    </textarea>
</div>
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/njhfm/1/).

Comment: Nice and clean answer.  Works perfectly.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so, when slideeffect is occured, the iframe don't appear correctly...

The solution I find is to rebind the editor, in the end of slideeffect.
But need to destroy it in hiding, else, some conflicts come.

jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/xzftW/18/

code :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function bindDiv(value) {
       kendo.bind($('#div'), '');
        $('#div').show("slide", { direction: "right" }, function(){
            resetme();
            kendo.bind($('#div'), kendo.observable({ TheValue: value }));
                $('#hide').click(function() {hideme() } ); 
        });        
    }
    $('#div').hide();
    $('#btn1').click(function () { bindDiv('hello'); });
    $('#btn2').click(function () { bindDiv('goodbye'); });    
});


function hideme()
{
    $('#div').hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, function(){    
       resetme();
    });
 }

function resetme()
{
     $('#div').html('<textarea data-role="editor" data-bind="value: TheValue"></textarea><button id="hide" type="button">Hide</button>');

}
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately this approach doesn't allow the editor to do its magic - it looks like it just makes the textarea visible.  No rich text editing - kendo isn't even aware that you've edited the value, so it doesn't update the MVVM model.  See http://jsfiddle.net/dschilling/xzftW/12/.  Edit the value in the textbox, then click hide.  You should see the edited value displayed in the console.  Instead the original value is displayed.

Comment: Thanks.  That does work.  Thank you for the effort you put into this.

Answer (score 1):

`"slide"` is a [jquery-ui effect](http://api.jqueryui.com/category/effects/) - as opposed to [jQuery "basic" effects](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/).

All jquery-ui effects work as follows : they wrap the selected nodes inside a node, animate the wrapper, then unwrap the content.

I don't know how Kendo reacts to this.

jQuery "basic" effects, on the other hand, leave the DOM be and modify the element's css porperties.

You can try to replace your effect with a call to [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/), or, as others have suggested, try to rebind or refresh your Kendo observers.